# How do you remove the breadcrumbs at the top of each page?

Tags: doxygen

At the top of each class/namespace/etc page, Doxygen includes a breadcrumb trail or file reference path (whatever you want to call it).

Leveraged graph from the web to show what I can't seem to remove

[image: leveraged graph from the web to show what I can't seem to remove]

How do I remove this? I have tried turning off any settings I can think of that have to do with generating TOC/Index, I have a custom layout file that has everything in the "navindex" section turned off,

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Looks like 1.8.10, quite an old version (from June 27, 2015) the current version is 1.9.2  so worthwhile to update and what happens with the later version. Also what are the setting in your doxygen settings file different from the default settings (in the newer version : `doxygen -x Doxyfile`). What is the structure of your directories in respect to the place of `abc.c` and `foo.h`

Comment: I'm using version 1.9.1; that graphic isn't the output that I am generating, it was just an example. Too much IP to be able to post what I'm generating. 
Settings that are different (from the HTML section): HTML_TIMESTAMP, HTML_FOOTER, and GENERATE_TREEVIEW. Tried other values but it didn't fix the problem, so I set them back to what they were originally.

Comment: Still to be able to help we need an up to date image (preferably with the current 1.9.3 version) and also a small example (especially as you changed `HTML_FOOTER` which is version sensitive)